# Import json using absolute path python

Tags: python

I'm using wadofstuff's serializer https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wadofstuff-django-serializers on django 1.5. However, it uses simplejson which is now deprecated so I have to go directly into the library file `wadofstuff/django/serializers/json.py` and change simplejson into json. The problem is that I cannot `import json` because the library file is named `json.py` as well, so it tries to load itself. I don't want to change the file name because other developers in my team will definitely kill me. Is there any way to import json from absolute path?

Thank you.

Comment: It really seems like you ought to file a bug, given that it was still being updated in 2012. And then implement the clean fix (rename the file to something other than json, and do the traditional try-import-json-except-import-simplejson fix) and submit it as a patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, and probably best, fix for this (in Python 2.x) is to not have a module that shadows the name of a top-level stdlib/site-packages module.

In other words, rename `json.py` to something else. Then you can just `import json` from within the renamed file (or, better, `try` that, and on `ImportError` fall back to `simplejson`, so you don't break 2.5 compatibility). Then just change whatever code was importing `serializers.json` to import the new thing.

You should be able to file a bug against the wadostuff package, and submit your patch, and it may make it into version 1.2. (There seems to be an update about once/year or so, and it doesn't seem too unreasonable to finally get up to speed with Python 2.6 and Django 1.5 in 2013…)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to remove the current directory from the search path.
Assuming `""` (denotes the current directory) is at the beginning of `sys.path` (the default):

```
sys.path.remove("")
import json
sys.path.insert(0, "")
```

Comment: I appreciate every hack like that for the smart thinking. But just for others who come here and read this approach: Never ever do this. You don't have to. There are a lot of other ways and every one of them is better than changing your system path.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this line on top of `json.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

This will tell Python that, while importing this module, it should look for modules only on sys.path and not relatively to it (see also http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports).

Edit:

Also note that the `wadofstuff`'s module doesn't actually import simplejson directly: `from django.utils import simplejson`. [Django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/utils/simplejson.py) will use the stdlib version by default *if* you don't have simplejson installed.

Comment: That almost works, except that `json.py` is already named `json`, and `import json` will still just return itself. If the problem were _another_ module in the package that wanted to import the stdlib module, this would be the answer.

Comment: @abnarnert You're wrongly assuming that the file 'json.py' is on sys.path. The full qualified name of that module is ``wadofstuff.django.serializers.json``, so it does not shadow the stdlib in anyway.

Comment: The `json.py` he's trying to do the import _from_ may not be on sys.path (hopefully it isn't), but the one he's try to import from within it definitely is. If it's being imported from outside the package as `wadofstuff.django.serializers.json` it'll work with `absolute_import`; if it's being imported through traditional import as `import json` from a sibling, it won't. If you've already checked and seen that it's not being imported the latter way anywhere, then I apologize, your answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

1, try change python's import-path:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/json.py/dir")
import json
```

2, try add  _ _ init _ _.py file to all dirs to your json.py, then you can use this

```
import a.b.c.json as myjson
```

3, if you dont want change any bit, try something deep with

```
__import__()
```

Comment: 1) would actually make things worse and 2) is already done in the library the OP writes about. And 3) is not really helpful?